# Qiskit primitives with commuting observables

Tags: qiskit-runtime, qiskit

Is there a way of bundling commuting observables in qiskit primitive estimator to save the number of shots?

With the new feature of Qiskit primitives, it is easy to sample observables for a specific circuit on any backend. There is also a feature to run multiple circuits corresponding to an equal number of observables. I would like to run the same circuit on multiple observables. I would like to exploit their commutativity and reduce the number of shots. I am not sure if the current estimators already do this, or if there is any way I could do this and save the number of circuit executions

Comment: See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/31834/9474)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer linked above, there are different Estimator implementations from different providers. The implementations of the [Aer Estimator](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/main/qiskit_aer/primitives/estimator.py) and Qiskit [Estimator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/primitives/estimator.html#Estimator) and [BackendEstimator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/primitives/backend_estimator.html) are open source, and you can see that:

1. the Qiskit Estimator performs an exact statevector calculation (so no grouping is performed or needeed)
2. both the Aer and Backend Estimator expose an `abelian_grouping` parameter that triggers the use of the [`group_commuting`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/9c8eb06984c91156eac078f3d2d73b4cf68370b4/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/symplectic/sparse_pauli_op.py#L984) method from Qiskit's `quantum_info` module.

As for the [Qiskit Runtime Estimator](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-runtime/blob/main/qiskit_ibm_runtime/estimator.py), the implementation is not open source, but my understanding is that it performs qubit-wise group commuting by default, at least for `resilience_level=0` (might be for all resilience levels), and this option is NOT configurable by users for the time being.

I hope this helps.